# Shared object creation: dangling symlink using make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to create a shared library using `gcc` and `make`. I have the following section in the Makefile to compile the shared library object:

```
# The library build step.
lib : $(DHLLOBJS)
    $(CC) $(XCFLAGS) $(SCFLAGS)$(SLIB).1 $(INCFLAGS) -o $(LIB_DIR)/$(SLIB).1.0 \
    $(DLOPATHS) $(LNKFLAGS)
    ln -sf $(LIB_DIR)/$(SLIB).1.0 $(LIB_DIR)/$(SLIB).1
    ln -sf $(LIB_DIR)/$(SLIB).1.0 $(LIB_DIR)/$(SLIB)
```

The above doesn't throw any compilation errors or file system errors but the symlinks are described as ***`dangling`*** as shown by a `chmod` command:

```
$ sudo chmod 0755 ../lib/*
chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink '../lib/libdhlim.so'
chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink '../lib/libdhlim.so.1'
```

and the `ls` command output below shows the lines 5 and 6 in red:

```
$ ls -la lib/
total 29
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   376 Jul  5 21:13 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Jul  5 21:13 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    21 Jul  5 21:13 libdhlim.so -> ./lib/libdhlim.so.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    21 Jul  5 21:13 libdhlim.so.1 -> ./lib/libdhlim.so.1.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23792 Jul  5 21:13 libdhlim.so.1.0
```

When I run the same set of commands manually, they work fine. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: There is no directory `lib` in the current directory. `./lib` is not the same as `../lib`. It should be either links to `./libdhlim.so.1.0` or `libdhlim.so.1.0`.

Comment: Consider making the last line e.g. `ln -sf $(SLIB).1.0 $(LIB_DIR)/$(SLIB)`

Comment: Your comments were helpful in realising the mistake and hence I tried with `${CURDIR}` as `${CURDIR}/lib/$(SLIB).1.0 $(LIB_DIR)/$(SLIB).1`.  It works but here I won't be able to use the variable LIB_DIR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use relative paths but don't create the links with the `ln` option `-r`.

Try these as the last two lines:

```
        ln -sfr $(LIB_DIR)/$(SLIB).1.0 $(LIB_DIR)/$(SLIB).1
        ln -sfr $(LIB_DIR)/$(SLIB).1.0 $(LIB_DIR)/$(SLIB)
```

- `-r, --relative`
         `with -s, create links relative to link location`

Comment: Great. That worked. I wasn't aware of that. I was also trying with `${CURDIR}` as `${CURDIR}/lib/$(SLIB).1.0 $(LIB_DIR)/$(SLIB).1`. But this is the best solution I think.

Comment: @skrowten_hermit Lovely! Yes, as long as one want to create them with relative paths, `-r`  is very helpful. :)